# CheckBox триггер C#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

У меня есть CheckBox, когда я нажимаю на него, происходит отдельное действие. 
В моём случаи это:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2.Visible = true;
}
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы при отключении (когда голочка снята) кнопка снова становилась невидимой:

```
button2.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Проверять чекнута ли она и выставлять `.Visible = false`?

Comment: А как проверку обработать?
If (cb1.Change) и тому подобное? @arrowd

Comment: `cb.IsChecked`, если мне не изменяет память. В студии же подсказочки есть.

Comment: @arrowd Я немного по другому сделал, но это тоже работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```csharp
button2.Visible = checkBox1.Checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё, понял, спасибо @arrowd!
Сделал через проверку:

```
if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
{
    button2.Visible = true;
}
else if (checkBox1.Checked == false)
{
    button2.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Ваш код легко схлопывается до варианта @Digital Core: посмотрите на оба присваивания, в правой части у вас значение совпадает с checkBox1.Checked - поэтому если есть возможность писать краткий выразительный код - пишите его, а не длинные затяжные конструкции.